# Como somar valores do checkbox e enviar esse valor para outra página pelo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tenho os checkboxes e abaixo tenho um botão. Gostaria que ao apertar este botão ele salvasse o valor da soma e enviasse para a página seguinte. Ex: se a soma deu três, gostaria que na outra página aparecesse esse 3.  Deixei abaixo apenas dois checkboxes, cada um valeria um, como posso fazer isso? Estou usando o framework Materialize.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--Import materialize.css-->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" charset="UTF-8/"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <h1>Formulário</h1>
        <form action="katzresult.html">
            <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox1" value = "1"/>
                    <span>1. Texto 1</span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <hr>
            <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id = "checkbox2" value = "1"/>
                    <span>2. Texto 2</span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <div id="container">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" name="action">Calcular
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

O JS da página 1:

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){

   var checados = document.querySelectorAll("form :checked");
   var soma = 0;
   for(var x=0; x < checados.length; x++){
      soma += parseInt(checados[x].value);
   }

   document.querySelector("[name=action]").value = soma;

}
```

E o JS da página 2:

```
var url = location.href; // pega a URL da página
var valor = url.match(/action=(\d+)$/); // pega o valor de "action"
```

Comment: Não pode colocar o button dentro do form?

Comment: Vc quer pegar esse "3" na outra página com JS tb?

Answer (score 1):

Coloque o botão dentro do form para que ele submeta o form. Não precisa colocar `type="submit"` no button porque ele já é por natureza `type="submit"`.

Coloque values nos checkboxes. Esses values serão somados. Por exemplo:

```
       ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
<input value="1" type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox1"/>
```

Coloque o endereço da outra página no `action` do form:

```
<form action="outrapagina.html">
```

Crie um *event handler* `onsubmit` para o formulário e some os `value` dos checkboxes fazendo um laço `for`.

Coloque o resultado da soma como `value` do button ao submeter o formulário.

O JS ficará assim:

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){

   var checados = document.querySelectorAll("form :checked");
   var soma = 0;
   for(var x=0; x < checados.length; x++){
      soma += parseInt(checados[x].value);
   }

   document.querySelector("[name=action]").value = soma;

}
```

Suponha que a soma dos values dos checkboxes seja 3, então ao submeter o formulário, será direcionado para a URL:

```
outrapagina.html?action=3
```

Repare que na URL possui um parâmetro `action` com valor `3`.

Na outra página você consegue recuperar esse valor da seguinte forma:

```
var url = location.href; // pega a URL da página
var valor = url.match(/action=(\d+)$/); // pega o valor de "action"
```

A variável `valor` será `3`.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela resposta, só tenho uma dúvida, a action na URL fica vazia...

Comment: Tem que colocar o botão dentro do form.

Comment: Eu coloquei, editei o código, poderia dar mais uma olhada? Não sei se acabei deixando algo passar...

Comment: Faz um teste: coloca no botão um `value`, assim: `<button value="3" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" name="action">`, e veja se chega na outra página o `?action=3`

Comment: Testei, Chega sim

Comment: Ok. Remove o value de teste e faça o seguinte: antes da linha `document.querySelector("[name=action]").value = soma;` coloca `alert(soma)` e veja se mostra o valor correto da soma

Comment: Ainda sim não funciona... :(